# Twitter Bootstrap Datepicker won't update input value

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code, but now i am stuck:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="/">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#datepicker').datepicker()
        .on('changeDate', function(ev){
            // Some code..
        });
</script>
```

I want the value of input field to update every time the new date is selected. I want the value to be the date, that was selected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var dp = $("#datepicker");

    dp.datepicker({
        format : 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    });

     dp.on('changeDate', function(ev){
       dp.val(ev.target.value);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do some crazy stuff for mine to work. Something about version perhaps? i don't know.

```
        var dt = $(".datepick");

        dt.datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        });

        dt.on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            var mDate = new moment(ev.date);

            $("input", dt).attr('value',mDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
        });
```

Yes, i am using moment js, it's because i am doing some date calculations on the page.

But it worked.

I needed the input to have the value so i could use jquery selectors to filter empty fields with `:not([value=''])` selector.

I hope it helps some body ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div class="input-group input-daterange">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2019-03-05">
    <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2019-03-14">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".input-daterange input").each(function(){
        $(this).datepicker('setValue');
});
```

Comment: It would be much better if you could provide some explanation for your answer. For more information, please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
        // Some code..
    });;
});
```

The date picker should be attache to the #datepicker element when the page is ready by putting it in

```
$(function() {
  //code
}
```

or

```
$(document).ready($function{
 //some code
});
```

or make sure that

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){});
```

is executed in a function before the #datepicker element is clicked on