# How to get the value of a textbox with bootstrap datepicker

Tags: asp.net

How can I get the value of the textbox with bootstrap datepicker?

When ever I pick a date, the value attribute does not change even though what is written in the textbox changes. I'm using ASP.NET so I'm relying on the .Text property which I believe retrieves the value attribute.

The default value of the textbox is the current date which is what I get after selecting another date.

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591159/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-wont-update-input-value

Comment: thanks for the reply. the field was disabled. i thought that i can change the value of the textbox via javascript even when it is disabled. my bad.

Comment: No problem. But if it was disabled, best thing to do is find out why it is (i.e. if you've disabled it in your code, or it already was, etc). Then work from there.